# How to get kubernetes applications to change deploy configs

Tags: kubernetes

I have two applications running in K8. `APP A` has write access to a data store and `APP B` has read access.

`APP A` needs to be able to change `APP B`'s running deployment.

How we currently do this is manually by kicking off a process in `APP A` which adds a new DB in the data store (say db `bob`). Then we do:

```
kubectl edit deploy A
```

And change an environment variable to `bob`. This starts a rolling restart of all the pods of `APP B`. We would like to automate this process.

Is there anyway to get `APP A` to change the deployment config of `APP B` in k8?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly answering your main question:

> Is there anyway to get a service to change the deployment config of another service in k8?

From my understanding you are calling it Service A and B for it's purpose in the real life, but to facilitate understanding I suggested an edit to call them `APP A` and `APP B`, because:

> In Kubernetes, a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#service-resource) is an **abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods** and a policy by which to access them (sometimes this pattern is called a micro-service).

So if in your question you meant:

"Is there anyway to get `APP A` to change the deployment config of `APP B` in k8?"

Then **Yes**,  you can give a pod admin privileges to manage other components of the cluster using the **`kubectl set env`** command to change/add envs.

In order to achieve this, you will need:

- [A Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions) with needed permissions in the namespace.

  - NOTE: In my example below since I don't know if you are working with multiple namespaces I'm using a [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole), granting `cluster-admin`  to a specific user. If you use only 1 namespace for these apps, consider a Role instead.
- A [ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) binding the permissions of the service account to a role of the Cluster.
- The [Kubectl client](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux) inside the pod (manually added or modifying the docker-image) on `APP A`

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Create a deployment to apply the cluster-admin privileges, I'm naming it `manager-deploy.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: manager-deploy
  labels:
    app: manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: manager
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: k8s-role    
      containers:
        - name: manager
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
```

- Create a deployment with a environment var, mocking your Service B. I'm naming it `deploy-env.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: env-deploy
  labels:
    app: env-replace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: env-replace
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: env-replace
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: k8s-role    
      containers:
        - name: env-replace
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
          env:
          - name: DATASTORE_NAME
            value: "john"
```

- Create a `ServiceAccount` and a `ClusterRoleBinding` with `cluster-admin` privileges, I'm naming it `service-account-for-pod.yaml` (notice it's `mentioned in manager-deploy.yaml`:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: k8s-role
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: k8s-role
```

- Apply the `service-account-for-pod.yaml`, `deploy-env.yaml`, `manager-deploy.yaml`and list current environment variables from `deploy-env` pod:

```
$ kubectl apply -f manager-deploy.yaml 
deployment.apps/manager-deploy created
$ kubectl apply -f deploy-env.yaml 
deployment.apps/env-deploy created
$ kubectl apply -f service-account-for-pod.yaml 
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/k8s-role created
serviceaccount/k8s-role created

$ kubectl exec -it env-deploy-fbd95bb94-hcq75 -- printenv
DATASTORE_NAME=john
```

- Shell into the `manager pod`, download the `kubectl` binary and apply the `kubectl set env deployment/deployment_name VAR_NAME=VALUE`:

```
$ kubectl exec -it manager-deploy-747c9d5bc8-p684s -- /bin/bash

root@manager-deploy-747c9d5bc8-p684s:/# curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
root@manager-deploy-747c9d5bc8-p684s:/# chmod +x ./kubectl
root@manager-deploy-747c9d5bc8-p684s:/# mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

root@manager-deploy-747c9d5bc8-p684s:/# kubectl set env deployment/env-deploy DATASTORE_NAME=bob
```

- Verify the `env var value` on the pod (notice that the pod is recreated when deployment is modified:

```
$ kubectl exec -it env-deploy-7f565ffc4-t46zc -- printenv
DATASTORE_NAME=bob
```

Let me know in the comments if you have any doubt on how to apply this solution to your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was not exactly what I needed but pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could give service A access to your cluster (install kubectl and allow traffic from that NAT of service A to your cluster master) and with some cron jobs or jenkins / ssh or something that will execute your commands do it. You can also do `kubectl patch` or get the current config of second deployment `kubectl get deployment <name> -o yaml --export > deployment.yaml` and edit it there with some regex/awk/sed and then apply although the --export method is getting deprecated so you might aswell on service A download the GIT repo and apply the new config like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers all (upvoted as they were both correct). I am just putting my own answer to document *exactly* what solved it for me.

In my case I just needed to make use of the [patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#patch-deployment-v1-apps) url available on k8. That plus the [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/PatchExample.java) example worked.

All I needed to do was create a service account to restrict who can patch where. Restrict that account to `Service A` and use the java client in `Service A` to update the chart of `Service B`. After that the pods would roll and done.